# Использование классов, реализующих обобщенный интерфейс

Tags: c#, ооп, архитектура, generics, интерфейс

Имеется следующая примерная структура классов и интерфейсов. В дальнейшем хочется реализоваться такую возможность, чтобы была функция (у отдельного класса, естественно), принимающая список различных источников (базовым классом всех будет являться Source) и возвращающая такую структуру данных (или объект), который бы содержал всю загруженную информацию со всех источников, переданных в аргументах. Важно то, что тип этой загружаемой информации может отличаться у разных источников информации.

**Вопрос: как это можно реализовать?**

```
public interface IDownloadMaximumInformation<T>
{
    T DownloadMaximumInformation(string url);
}

public class Datatype1 { /*...*/}
public class Datatype2 { /*...*/}

public class Source {/*...*/ }

public class Source1 : Source, IDownloadMaximumInformation<Datatype1>
{
    public Datatype1 DownloadMaximumInformation(string url)
    {
        //...///
        return new Datatype1();//Условно, в реальности будет по-другому
    }
}

public class Source2 : Source, IDownloadMaximumInformation<Datatype2>
{
    public Datatype2 DownloadMaximumInformation(string url)
    {
        //...///
        return new Datatype2();//Условно, в реальности будет по-другому
    }
}
```

Comment: сделайте базовый класс `DataTypeBase` и собирайте коллекцию `List<DataTypeBase>` элементов.

Comment: @tym32167 А как правильнее при этом сохранять информацию и о типе загружаемых данных. Потом придется же их интерпретировать как-то? Может, использовать что-то наподобие словаря?

Comment: зависит от того, что вы с данными делать собрались

Comment: @tym32167 Для каждого из типов данных может быть свой путь. Он зависит исключительно от свойств (в прямом смысле этого слова, а не в терминах ООП). На выходе из этой функции хотелось бы иметь возможность получать все то, что она загрузила из источников и знать тип этих данных, чтобы потом можно было к нему привести из базового класса-типа DataTypeBase.

Comment: @tym32167 Еще хотелось бы спросить, существует ли какой-нибудь способ узнать, какой тип данных данный класс поддерживает для возвращения при обращении к данной функции шаблонного интерфейса (по сути "специализацию шаблона", если так можно назвать) ? Это нужно чтобы уменьшить объем кода при написании функции для загрузки информации со всех источников. Я так понимаю, что это возможно с помощью рефлексии. Првильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что вам нужна такая сложность, но допустим у нас есть интерфейс

```
public interface IDataType { }
```

И наследники

```
public class Datatype1 : IDataType { /*...*/}
public class Datatype2 : IDataType { /*...*/}
```

Определим интерфейс обработчика

```
public interface IHandler<T>
{   
    void Handle(T item);
}
```

Напишем 2 обработчика для разных типов

```
public class Datatype1Handler : IHandler<Datatype1>
{       
    public void Handle(Datatype1 item)=>    
        Console.WriteLine("Handled at Datatype1Handler with love");
}

public class Datatype2Handler : IHandler<Datatype2>
{
    public void Handle(Datatype2 item) =>
        Console.WriteLine("Handled at Datatype2Handler no love");
}
```

Далее, я использую словарь как реестр зарегистрированных типов, вы можете использовать тут что угодно

```
var registry = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
registry.Add(typeof(IHandler<Datatype1>), new Datatype1Handler());
registry.Add(typeof(IHandler<Datatype2>), new Datatype2Handler());
```

Теперь, преставим, что у нас есть данные разных типов в списке

```
var list = new List<IDataType>() {new Datatype1(), new Datatype2(), new Datatype2(), };
```

Ну, теперь пробежимся по списку, найдем нужные обработчики и вызовем их

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    var targetType = typeof(IHandler<>).MakeGenericType(item.GetType());
    var handler = registry[targetType];
    targetType.GetMethod("Handle").Invoke(handler, new[] { item });
}
```

На выходе получаем

```
Handled at Datatype1Handler with love
Handled at Datatype2Handler no love
Handled at Datatype2Handler no love
```

**UPD**

Поменяем интерфейс хандлера

```
public interface IHandler
{
    bool CanHandle(IDataType item);
    void Handle(IDataType item);
}
```

Несколько хандлеров

```
public class Datatype1Handler : IHandler
{
    public bool CanHandle(IDataType item) => item is Datatype1; 

    public void Handle(IDataType item) =>
    Console.WriteLine("Handled at Datatype1Handler with love"); 
}

public class Datatype2Handler : IHandler
{
    public bool CanHandle(IDataType item)=> item is Datatype2;  
    public void Handle(IDataType item) =>
        Console.WriteLine("Handled at Datatype2Handler no love");   
}

public class AllTypesHandler : IHandler
{
    public bool CanHandle(IDataType item) => true;
    public void Handle(IDataType item) =>
        Console.WriteLine("All types handler!");
}
```

Далее, поскольку все хандлеры у нас имеют конструкторы по умолчанию, можно пробежаться по сборке и насоздовать их

```
// парсим текущую сборку, находим и создаем все хандлеры
var registry = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsClass && typeof(IHandler).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                .Select(t=>Activator.CreateInstance(t))
                .Cast<IHandler>()
                .ToArray();
```

Уже привычный список данных

```
var list = new List<IDataType>() {new Datatype1(), new Datatype2(), new Datatype2(), };
```

Обработка их хандлерами

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    foreach(var handler in registry)
    if (handler.CanHandle(item)) handler.Handle(item);
}
```

Теперь хандлеры не связаны с типами, каждый хандлер сам решает, может он обрабатывать данные или нет по своей собственной логике. Вывод ожидаем

```
Handled at Datatype1Handler with love
All types handler!
Handled at Datatype2Handler no love
All types handler!
Handled at Datatype2Handler no love
All types handler!
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! На самом деле, такая сложность (естественно говорю про свой случай) не является необходимой. Пока не хотелось бы использовать контейнер, так как эта не функция (или будем говорить будущий класс, в котором эта функция будет) не являются самым верхним уровнем, с которого было бы действительно удобно использовать контейнер. Можно ли именно возвращать что-либо из функции, чтобы сохранилась еще и информация о реальном типе, к которому относится объект, а не просто список объектов типа BaseDataType. В любом случае, за ответ большое спасибо!

Comment: @PracticeMakesPerfect если наличе контейнера - это всё, что вас тут смущает, то я обновил ответ, поменял его на словарь.

Comment: Понял. А можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы этот словарь заполнялся не вручную, так как потенциально может быть много типов данных и загрузчиков к ним. Хотелось бы, чтобы эта привязка работала именно при подаче конкретных загрузчиков в виде списка загрузчиков. Плюс как быть с тем, что несколько видов загрузчиков могут, например, отдавать одинаковые типы данных? Словарь же работает с уникальным ключом. Получается, надо к ключу привязывать не один объект, а список этих однотипных объектов. Правильно?

Comment: @PracticeMakesPerfect вы меняете требования на лету, из за этого приходится переписывать решение несколько раз. Было бы неплохо видеть все ваши требования с самого начала в вопросе. Я добавил обновление в ответ, теперь список хандлеров заполняется автоматом из текущей сборки, каждый хандлер сам решает, может он обрабатывать элемент данных или нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вопрос решен!